# help with a html layout using css

Tags: javascript, html

Today I founda  jquery marquee plugin to make the content scroll smoothly,this is the demo:
[jQuery Marquee Demo](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html)

Since I want to use it in my application,so I make some modifition:

This is the example:

[My example](http://jsfiddle.net/aa9NE/)

However I can not make the layout with what I want .

I just want the whole page splitted to three row:

The head(h1),the content which will be the container of the scroll element(div.demo),and the div.foot.

Now I want the div.foot stay at the bottom of the page at a fixed position.

And the div.demo should expand its height to take up all the space between the h1 and the div.foot.

BTW,there is not a scroll bar exist,when the (div.demo marquee div) contain too many contents,I wonder if the scrol bar can show?

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aa9NE/2/

Comment: No,I want the div.foot stay at the bottom of the page. THere should no space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/aa9NE/3/ — hope that actually does what you meant. The CSS contains a few comments.